# How do I resolve an "Error reading signed content." error when installing ADT 23.0.2 in Eclipse 4.4 on OSX

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adt

I've been trying to install the Android Developer Tools (ADT 23.0.2) in Eclipse 4.4 on OSX . When I do, I get the following error message:

> An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
>
> session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
>
> Error reading signed content.
>
> error in opening zip file

This problem happens both when I try to install it directly from the Android Repository, and when I try to install it from a file that I've downloaded locally.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094583/eclipse-error-when-try-install-plugin

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same issue, and I found that if I installed the components one at a time (instead of the whole lot all at once) it worked... But then a week or so later I tried installing some other Eclipse software from the Luna repository (it was the C++ Developer Tools) and I got the same error. Then after a bit of Googling I found this: [eclipse error when try install plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094583/eclipse-error-when-try-install-plugin)

So basically if you delete all the **artifacts.xml** files under your eclipse directory the problem goes away. Here are the commands I used:

```
cd /opt/eclipse
find -name artifacts.xml -execdir rm {} \;
```

I don't really know what the artifacts.xml files are for, but I am just happy to be able to install stuff again without having to start from a fresh Eclipse install. I hope you find this useful. :-)

Comment: Sorry the Solution did not work in my case. it was only about specific plugin `org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full 11.0.18` somehow those bundled jre's require JRE11 execution environment, but yet setting the Environment to a JRE11 did not have any effects

Answer (score 1):

Your error occur by you deleted file in plugins
You need:
Delete file 
You search file artifacts.xml 
in folder ..\jee-neon\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi
(My folder is: C:\Users\hotli\eclipse\jee-neon\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi)
After you delete file content text this "android"

Next open file artifacts.xml in folder: .p2\pool (My folder: C:\Users\hotli.p2\pool) this is place content all plugin in Eclipse
After you search this text "android"
Delete all atribute  content text "android"

Next save file and install plugin again
Note: turn off your IDE eclipse before do it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how representative my experience has been, but the problem went away for me after I applied all the availble Eclipse updates.

Note: Based on previous successes, I am using an old Eclipse, 2020-12, and bringing up a new machine, so I was starting from a freshly-installed 2020-12, "Embedded C/C++" flavor.