# Error when try install plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install a plugin in Eclipse Luna. I installed Papyrus and am trying to install SWT designer, but before the download/installation is completed I get an error:

> ```
> An error occurred during the
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
> session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard,
> phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust,
> operand=, action=). Error reading signed content. error in opening zip
> file
> ```

After this error I can't install anything and the install manager does not work anymore and shows me the same error all the time only one way I delete the current Eclipse directory and extract it again.

This time I install Papyrus, SWT designer and some other, but I get the error between install another plugin again. This is wrong if I get an error on install any of plugin reinstalling Eclipse and the other plugin again.

Is this a bug or a problem?

Answer (score 136):

OK finally i found the solution for solve this problem. I don't know why Eclipse is showing me this error and i don't know if this is the best solution. I solve my problem with delete the **artifacts.xml** file in Eclipse root directory.

After deleting this file try to install that plugin again but this time after few second everything completes and works perfectly.

**UPDATE:**
If you get that error again then just go to Eclipses' root directory and search for "artifacts.xml" and delete all the files is in the result ;)

Comment: This works! I was trying to install GWT plugin for Eclipse Luna and this solved my issue. Many thanks!

Comment: I was getting this error trying to update Luna and simply renaming the file to `artifacts.xml.old` did it. Eclipse is indeed a strange beast...

Comment: You can even search for the violating artifacts in the artifacts.xml and delete  only what's necessary.

Comment: while installing plugin ,eclipse Luna automatically keeps creating those artifacts.xml files, so while plugin installation i kept deleting them and installation become successful.After installation finished those files again appeared but causing any harm.

Comment: I had to remove/rename the artifacts.xml from the `.p2`folder in my user-dir

Comment: I had to download the plugin's zipped repository, copy the files in /repository/plugins to /user/.p2/pool/plugins and then run the online installer.  Quite odd, but seems installer is not copying the downloaded files to eclipse's p2/pool/plugins

Answer (score 23):

1. Remove the `artifacts.xml` from the folder.
2. Keep a copy of  it in some other location (preferably external devices such as pendrive or hard disks etc).
3. Restart Eclipse.
4. Install the software plugin you want to install (it will ask for permission again).
5. After installation paste the `artifacts.xml` file back into the eclipse folder.
6. Restart eclipse and set the SDK location.
7. Code to death!!! ;p

Answer (score 7):

Run Eclipse as an administrator, then try to install the plugin again via help->Install New Software. it worked for me

Comment: How do you run eclipse as an administrator?

Comment: I use windows and there you can simply right-click on the eclipse executable and select "Run as administrator". I am not sure about macOS and linux

Comment: ok yeah I use manjaro kde linux, I found a solution on how to run eclipse as admin/sudo [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249098/how-do-i-run-eclipse-as-sudo). From this I found out if you use ubuntu you should use: `gksu eclipse` and in my case (manjaro KDE) or other KDE distributions use: `kdesu eclipse`. From there I was then able to install new software again

Comment: I forgot to note but you need to run those commands in the command line

Answer (score 1):

I installed E4 RCP Patch(bugzillas 445122)(Install new software -> Eclipse 4.4.1 Patches for bug 445122) and this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this problem while updating eclipse's internal software. I discovered that the jar file org.eclipse.epp.mpc.help.ui_1.5.2.v20161004-1655.jar (found in the error details) in the eclipse plugins directory was corrupted (7-Zip was unable to inspect its contents). I redownloaded and manually replaced this file with one downloaded from [their site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201610111000/plugins/org.eclipse.epp.mpc.help.ui_1.5.2.v20161004-1655.jar), and I was then able to install the software without an issue. Hope this helps :)

(If it was a different JAR file for you, you can click "show directory contents" on [this page](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201610111000/plugins/) and download the one you need.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is typically a damaged jar in the bundle pool. **You can fix this without manually editing files**:

- run the Eclipse installer ("Oomph")
- select "Bundle pools" from the menu
- hit the "Analyze agent" button
- wait until the column "Damaged Artifacts" doesn't show a percent number anymore (scanning has finished)

You can now filter the bottom view to show only damaged artifacts, and choose to either delete or repair them (repair means to download them again from the Internet).

Answer (score -1):

Recently i had this issue & i did a few workaround to make things right,

Drag and dropped from official page, normally eclipse restarts after the download, and a pop-up will ask us to select the svn connectors from list. but that didn't happened to me.

1. **Install svn Plugin.** (By drag and drop or install new software or any)
2. After this goto `window->preferences->Team->svn`
3. select `Connector` Tab and click `Get connectors` Button then the prompt will appear select any one `connector` to get it done (i use NativeHL 1.8).

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by editing the artifacts.xml.

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Edit the artifacts.xml.
3. Find and delete previous entries related to the plugin you are
   trying to install.
4. Save artifacts.xml.

After this you should be able to start Eclipse normally and install your plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I tried many solution from here including the one which says **removing artifacts.xml** and try installing with opening software with **Run as Administrator** also tried to install from the Help option **"Install new software"** none of this worked for me.

***Then I updated to the latest version of JDK and it worked perfectly.***
I hope this help you.

Thanks.
Vijay P.

Answer (score -2):

`org.aspectj.weaver_1.8.10.201704242114.jar`
File will be downloaded for google, and it can be placed in `eclipse/plugin/org.aspectj.weaver_1.8.10.201704242114.jar`
 can be replaced with older jar file.........it can be solved for your problem...........

Answer (score -3):

Try this from the Eclipse marketplace
1. Click Help>Eclipse marketPlace (Eclipse marketPlace dialog box will open)
2. Type the name of your plugin (ex: type SWT Designer) in the find edit box, make sure to keep default values for All markets and all categories, and click go button.
3. The page will refresh and display all plugins that have swt designer in their name.
4. Click intsall or update button on the one that fits your needs.
5. The installation or update will be done successfully.
6. Restart your eclipse
7. The installation will be fine.

Answer (score -5):

It's a failure in Eclipse.

Try to uninstall it then download it from: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

and install it.

Comment: i download eclipse 2 days ago, also i check update before going to install plugin AND i do the uninstall and reinstall it before not the absolute and good solution if get error again, i can't do anything (the plugin installer doesn't work anymore !!!)

Comment: You need to remove everything related to eclipse in your computer.

Comment: I do this before, delete the eclipse and all other thing with/for it before coming here for ask but nothing change, this is not the first time I get this error in this 2 days

Comment: ,no just on that plugin i was trying to install in the past

Comment: Then there is a problem in the plugin, try to download it from somewhere else.