# What is the artifacts file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

What is the **artifacts.xml** file in Eclipse root directory i mean what does it do? Is this file important or not because i delete this file for solve one of my problem on this question: [Error when try install plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094583/eclipse-error-when-try-install-plugin/25095673)

I use the Eclipse luna
**Edit:**
I ask this because I want to know after delete this file is it possible that there are problems in the future to come

Comment: It is used by the Eclipse p2 installation manager. I am not familiar enough with p2 to say how critical it is.

Comment: Thanks I ask this because I want to know after delete this file is it possible that there are problems in the future to come