# Can't open Eclipse after installing ADT Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-adt

I just followed the steps on http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download to download and install the ADT plugin for Eclipse on my Mac. As soon as it finished downloading, I tried opening Eclipse to finish configuring the ADT. I, however, cannot open Eclipse anymore. All I get is the following error:

[image: error message]

How can I fix this error and get Eclipse to open again? What are the correct steps to successfully install the ADT plugin?

Comment: try this :http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/

Comment: @N5. Tried that already. Not the problem. Would get error message that from unidentified developer if that was the problem. It seems that the new Android ADT files somehow messed up the rest of my eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get Eclipse to open again **without a complete reinstallation**, remove all the bad ADT files, and then successfully install the ADT plugin with the following steps:

<sup>(I don't know if this method is correct, but it worked)</sup>

#### Get Eclipse to open:

1. Download a new copy of Eclipse into a different folder.
2. From the new Eclipse folder, copy **only** the **Eclipse.app** file into the old Eclipse root directory.

I was then able to open Eclipse by clicking on the **new Eclipse.app** in my **old Eclipse folder**. All my old projects and preferences were still there.

#### Delete Bad ADT Files:

1. In Eclipse Help > Installation Details > select all Android files and click uninstall
2. In Eclipse Help > Eclipse Marketplace > search for adt > uninstall the Android Development Tools for Eclipse

#### Reinstall the ADT Plugin:

I then had problems reinstalling the ADT Plugin and was getting the following error message:

> An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase...

Following the directions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094583/eclipse-error-when-try-install-plugin), I deleted the **artifacts.xml** file in the Eclipse root directory. I then relaunched Eclipse and was able to install the ADT Plugin through Help > Eclipse Marketplace > search for ADT > click the install button on the ADT package > relaunch Eclipse.

---

### Update Note:

As mentioned in the [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), since June 2015, the Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported and it is recommended to switch to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem, is try restarting the system and reopen the eclipse, if it doesn't solve then next possible way is to re-download the ADT package once again.