# Install C/C++ Plugin in STS 3.7.0

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, spring-tool-suite

I'm currently using STS 3.7.0 on Windows 64 bit machine to Develop Spring & Java projects. Now I need to develop C/C++ projects as well. I searched on the internet but could only find links for C/C++ plugins for eclipse. How should I install C/C++ plugin in STS and what name should I search for because I don't want to use another IDE for just C/C++ projects.Please Help

**EDIT 1:**

Tried using the Install new software option as mentioned by user @Vovka in the answer section. I got the following error message..

[image: STS ERRor]

Please suggest what to do now??

Answer (score 0):

You need Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Tooling)

The CDT can be installed into an existing Eclipse using the "Install New Software..." dialog and entering the p2 repository URLs listed below.

see urls here:
https://eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

Comment: @Vovka...I took your advice and used the "Install New Software" option but got an error..The screen shot of that error is displayed in the above edited question..

Comment: delete/rename artifacts.xml at the root eclipse folder
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094583/eclipse-error-when-try-install-plugin