# Installation Failed With An Error (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse

When I try to install the installation finish with an error : installation failed with an error - show log , and this happening even if I run it as admin I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64bits , when I click on show log this is what I see :

```
    [2017-04-03 20:33:34] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_121-b13
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.neon
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.6.0.v20161125-0947, build=2790, branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.6.0.v20161128-0928, build=2790, branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.6.0.v20161019-0656, build=2790, branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Neon))
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Offline = false
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Mirrors = true
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Resolving 23 requirements from 3 repositories to D:\Nouveau dossier (2)\eclipse
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement epp.package.java [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000
[2017-04-03 20:33:34] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2017-04-03 20:33:37] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
[2017-04-03 20:33:37] Computing prerequisite plan
[2017-04-03 20:33:41] Collecting 1 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon
[2017-04-03 20:33:42] Downloading epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2017-04-03 20:33:42] Collected 1 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon in 0.669s
[2017-04-03 20:33:42] Collecting 3 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000
[2017-04-03 20:33:46] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2017-04-03 20:33:46] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2017-04-03 20:33:46] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2017-04-03 20:33:46] Collected 3 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000 in 3.681s
[2017-04-03 20:33:46] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2017-04-03 20:33:46] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
```

I can't write the all code but it's something like that if you could help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your JDK is also 64-bit, and make sure the version of Eclipse you have downloaded is 64-bit. If everything is not aligned (system, JDK, IDE) as 64-bit you will get all kinds of strange errors and your IDE will not start.

UPDATE:

The issue occurs when you are installing a plug-in.
Please see this post:

- [Error when try install plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094583/error-when-try-install-plugin)

Or, if you don't want to do through all that, I suggest downloading a bare-bones version of Eclipse (no PD2 plugins built-in, just generic) and using the Marketplace to grab the extra plug-ins you want manually.

Comment: Yes everything is 64bits my system , the eclipse version and the jdk

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is still not resolved even after ensuring you have the right JDK installed for your machine, try using the **advanced mode** located under the overflow menu on the right-hand side of the eclipse installation window. This installation mode worker for me and several of my friends. You can also follow the [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKTSRS-e1sQ)