# Can anyone help me with installing the correct version of eclipse to use for developing android mobile applications

Tags: android, eclipse

Can anyone help me with installing the correct version of eclipse to use for developing android mobile applications with the associated plug ins needed

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Comment: does this use eclipse though as it is for university and when it comes to assignment we need to submit an eclipse project

Comment: you should use android studio. new updates won't come in eclipse now onwards.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: yes i know but can't as we have been told to use eclipse and not android studio i have eclipse installed but when i use it in university it has the emulator the one i downloaded at home doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These **videos** by *me* :) can help you to set up *[Android](http://developer.android.com/index.html) development environment* using [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/home/index.php).

Here's the link : [Set up android.](https://www.facebook.com/Programalecious)

**Caution :** If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving projects, see [Migrating to Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

Comment: when installing eclipse following your first video when i go to the website it doesn't have the Eclipse Standard

Comment: @amb101293 plz write the name of video you've watched. I've opened it now and its working.

Comment: The "Eclipse Standard" package is not provided any more, but you should be able to use "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" just as well. If you really want to go back to the last release of the "Standard" package, you can get it here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2

Comment: Actually, it looks like it is still available for the latest Eclipse (Luna, 4.4) here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Luna/R

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ there is no standard one to download and also to download the adk dosent work

Comment: i have the standard version downloading i currently have the luna version installed and the jse installed cant get the adk tho and when i try to install it through eclipse i get an error so it dosent install

Comment: @amb101293 you can use eclipse IDE as well. [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR1a/eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32.zip)

Comment: installing software has encountered a problem

An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
Error reading signed content.
error in opening zip file

Comment: Do you really want to use eclipse? if yes then I can make a torrent for you of the version that I am using _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)_

Comment: @amb101293 plz check this [How do I resolve an “Error reading signed content.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805954/how-do-i-resolve-an-error-reading-signed-content-error-when-installing-adt-23)

Comment: i need to use eclipse as it is what we have been told we need to use we dont have an option i would be very greatfull if you could do that for me

Comment: write your email address i'll mail you the torrent file

Comment: amb101293@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: @amb101293 check your mail

Comment: just keeps saying connecting to peers but i need to put my laptop off just now

Answer (score 0):

As Petey suggested in his comment, I would recommend giving AndroidStudio a spin as it is very well suited to Android programming. However, take a look at the eclipse ADT plugin which can be installed via the eclipse marketplace or a direct download from Google ([Google ADT page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)).

That should give you enough information to get things rolling, but again I would strongly recommend trying to switch over to AndroidStudio. I think you will find the entire experience easier to get into and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) :)

P.S. Why do people still use Eclipse while there is a GREAT tool for developing Android applications?