# Error installing Eclipse IDE on windows

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-8, installation

Hello everyone this is my first question here so I apologize for any missed expectations.

EDIT 1:

Downloaded Eclipse from : https://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/products/eclipse-inst-win64.exe

64-bit Windows 8

JDK Dir: C:\Program Files\Java

/Edit 1

I need to install the `Eclipse` IDE for Java programming for my Computer Science class and I have been trying for two days now with no success. I tried both the 64 and 32 bit installations and I get the exact same error. It's very frustrating because whenever I search all people talk about are "plug-ins".

Here is the error I get when installing:

```
[2015-09-17 13:30:06] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2015-09-17 13:30:34] An error was detected while performing the engine                  operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2015-09-17 13:30:34] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:282)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:523)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:328)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:709)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2971)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2900)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2881)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2775)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1151)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$27(SimpleVariablePage.java:1030)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$18.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:976)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_Techies_eclipse_java-latest-released2_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error with signed content.
  java.security.SignatureException: An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Techies\.p2\pool\features\org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature_3.7.0.v201502261749
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2900)
```

This goes on even more will post the entire thing if needed but hoping there is something obvious I am missing. I have tried re-installing `JDK`, rebooting, re-downloading `Eclipse`, installing 32-bit versions of `Eclipse` and JDK and 64-bit for both. I also system restored to before I started any of it and tried again on a clean boot and got the same error.

Comment: How exactly are you installing? Did you download from Eclipse site? Update the question with exact Eclipse and JDK versions.

Comment: Can you mention your JDK installation dir?

Comment: **64 or 32 bit** Operating system,which one u r using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just experienced a similar problem. Running the installer as administrator solved the problem for me.

So right click on the installer file (eclipse-inst-win64.exe) and then click on Run as administrator. Now just follow the prompts and you should be fine.

In case it matters, I did not update the installer, because it restarts and probably (i'm not sure) it won't restart in administrator mode.

Btw this was on a 64bit Windows 8.1 machine.

Also have a look at these two threads:

- [How do I resolve an "Error reading signed content." error when installing ADT 23.0.2 in Eclipse 4.4 on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805954/how-do-i-resolve-an-error-reading-signed-content-error-when-installing-adt-23)
- [Error when try install plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094583/eclipse-error-when-try-install-plugin)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try this... I have had to do this before and over looked it. Thanks!

Comment: You can update the installer, it still runs elevated.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even installing with Administrator Privileges in C:/Program Files/ might cause errors like timeouts. It's always better to install in a partition other than the C Drive (Non Operating System Drive).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had tow version of eclipse in my PC. To fix this issue, I changed the bundle repository during the installation phase.

Normaly you can find the bundle at the following path: `C:\Users\<name>\.p2`

Answer (score 0):

A workmate overheard me cursing about a very similar issue.

He had me uninstall NetBeans (installed on all the machines here).

The previous suggestions seemed to get me closer, but ditching NetBeans appears to have put me over.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. I had a different version installed in my system. So we need to delete that .p2 folder first and then install it.

Go to `C:\Users\<your name>\.p2`

and delete `.p2` folder and again try to install it. This worked for me.